# Can a bullet/finless rocket shape be a stable lifting body?

Tags: aerodynamics, hypersonic

Consider a reentry vehicle that looks like this

[image]

If this re-entered the atmosphere from orbit, presupposing a sufficiently forward CG, could it stabilizer into a nose-first lifting attitude?

I'm thinking that as the AoA increases, the s shape will begin to behave like a canard planform, where the nosecone is the canard as it has a higher AoA (the bottom surface does, with the top surface being inactive), while the main body is the main wing.

Comment: [Previous discussions](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4151/should-we-allow-questions-which-are-likely-answerable-by-the-experts-here-but-a) have somewhat agreed that non-aviation aerodynamics questions are offtopic here. I can see how this one might be borderline so I'll not mod-hammer it just yet. Lets see what the community decide but please all review the linked meta (and consider voting on the answers you agree/disagree with if it's the first time you've seen it).

Comment: The question of on/off topic hinges on the distinction of whether this is an "aircraft". Technically that is something which gains lift from the air - this qualifies. Others distinguish that it must be piloted either directly or remotely, a bullet does not qualify. Is a reentry vehicle "piloted"? Hence my assertion that this is borderline.

Comment: This is basically what the Falcon 9 booster does, except it has both reaction control thrusters as well as active aerodynamic control surfaces to control attitude, so it doesn't need to be aerodynamically stable.

Comment: Define "stable lifting body". It is not a real concept in generic terms (speed matter, with enough speed you cannot be "stable"). Many reentry capsule (so bullet like shape) have some aerodynamic lift, but AFAIK none "stable" (which I think it is impossible on such speeds: just think about it: low weight, but high speed, so passing different layers of atmosphere at very high speed, so high forces (higher then weight), so unstable).

Comment: You'll most probably get a better answer on [space.stackexchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @sophit I doubt it. I came here from r the aerodynamic experts

Comment: Instinctively I would answer no.  That's why rifle barrels have rifling, and why footballs are thrown with a spiral.  Because there is no aerodynamic means to provide stability, so they must be stabilized gyroscopically.  And instinctively, if the CG was forward it would stabilize like a dart.  Aerodynamically seeking the path of least resistance.  Because what property of a forward CG might produce a positive AOA?  Conceptually it doesn't seem worthy of serious consideration.

Comment: P.S. If there are phenomena in the hypersonic/re-entry realm that are over my head and make this plausible, then please improve the question and I will delete the comment above.  Otherwise I'd be happy to expand it into a proper answer.

Comment: Really sorry that a reference to a proven design was downvoted and deleted.  Anything to do with basic fundamentals of aviation seems to have some our site members fleeing in horror.  Short answer, look at an arrow.  Now try to make it a glider.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni, I don't totally agree with deleting your answer, but it was really an act of mercy since you didn't answer the question.  It was a reasonable comment, that's all.

Comment: @MichaelHall fundamental research (gaining full understanding) involves building a proper foundation of facts.  Have a look a the Pyramids.  Now look at Peter Kampf's answer.

Comment: You continue to display a remarkable ability to deny and deflect.  You posed a few relevant counter question to provoke thought, (a technique I like) but again, you didn’t answer the question.  Hints are not answers.  They just aren’t.

Comment: @MichaelHall sometimes I try to steer the OP in the right direction, but your advice is well taken, and I will work on being more concise.

Answer (score 5):

**Definitely No!**

Your rocket qualifies as a slender body. [Slender body theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slender-body_theory) says that the center of pressure is near the tip, regardless of Mach number. This means that a small side force caused by a nonzero angle of attack or sideslip will amplify this angle. In other words, the rocket will be unstable in pitch and yaw. Catastrophically so if you are in a re-entry.

Most lift will occur on the nosecone and the rear body will contribute almost none. A finless rocket cannot be stabilized at any angle of attack but will [tumble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OacVy8_nJi0) uncontrollably.

Comment: Won't the CP move back as the AoA rises, until it reaches the CG?

Comment: So, now we add stabilizer [fins](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nike_Hercules) to help control these tendencies, or keep some [instability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterosaur) a for better manuvering.

Comment: @Abdullah No, it will stay where it is until you are almost orthogonal to the flow. Remember what happens in a deep spin: Only the airplane nose will experience significant aerodynamic forces (apart from simple drag), the rest will have fully separated flow. The final posture will be orthogonal to the flow and spinning, after lots of tumbling around. Unless it breaks apart during the tumbling phase, which is very likely.

Comment: Why would we care about flow separation at those speeds?

Comment: @Abdullah We care about what happens at the opposite end of flow separation: Massive heat and aerodynamic loads over the full surface of the rocket. And the aero loads are purely drag. I understand your question that you care about lift.

Comment: How can that huge body produce no lift?

Comment: @Abdullah Please look into slender body theory. Basically, lift is only added where the width of the body increases. All what is coming behind does not contribute because the flow bending has happened already.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says it is for Stokes flow in very low Re numbers. I am at a loss as to how that has any relevance in hypersonic flow.

Comment: @Abdullah There is no Mach influence in slender body theory.

Comment: But the high speed will lead to very high Re numbers?

Comment: @PeterKämpf back in my skydiving days I experimented with trying to hold myself inverted with my body straight, head at the bottom. Terminal velocity went way up, probably to about 150kt, and in no time I would be gyrating in a kind of conical pattern that was impossible to control.  Going back to a flat arch position, the deceleration back to normal terminal velocity, the sensation was almost like falling into a swimming pool.

Comment: @Abdullah Also, viscosity is not part of slender body theory. Thus, no Re influence.

Comment: So Wikipedia lied

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? The air thrown outward at the very tip of the nose blocks airflow to everything behind, causing the rest of the vehicle to be in a vacuum

Comment: @AbdullahisnotanAmalekite No, no air is thrown outward and there is no vacuum. But equal pressure on top and bottom except for the stations where the body widens.